# bat-файл, который запустит еще несколько bat-файлов

Tags: bat

Всем привет!
Подскажите, есть 3 файла типа .bat, которые в свою очередь производят запуск определенного проекта, **задача:**
Написать .bat файл, которые запустит еще 3 .bat файла, которые и запускают проект, важный момент все эти 3 .bat файла должны быть запущены на определенных учетных записях. (т.е. каждый .bat файл должен быть запущен на своей учетной записи Windows) проблема только в реализации запуска на отдельных учетках, если кто сталкивался, отпишите, пожалуйста, что использовали и можно ли решить проблему через runas?

Comment: Можно решить с помощью runas, если политика безопасности не запрещает оный и не требует явного ввода пароля руками

Comment: К сожалению, придется вводить пароль